# Subscription and observer patterns in typescript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, publish-subscribe

I am really confused here. Can we regard subscription pattern to be the same as the observer pattern? I'm watching a typescript tutorial video and Max the instructor did something with what he called subscription pattern. I didn't understand the pattern and searched through Google for a better explanation but all I can get thus far are answers relating to the observer pattern.

Comment: The Observer pattern involves the concepts of Publishers and Subscribers. Subscription wouldn't be considered a pattern in and of itself. There are a lot of bad tutorials out there. Be careful. I'm not saying this is a bad tutorial, I haven't watched it, but don't grant it too much authority

Comment: Publish/subscribe messaging, or pub/sub messaging, is a form of asynchronous service-to-service communication used in serverless and microservices architectures. In a pub/sub model, any message published to a topic is immediately received by all of the subscribers to the topic.